# Replace letters in a string with an underscore in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

How do you replace every letter in a string with an underscore in javascript.

For example I would like the string of "name" to be replaced with _ _ _ _.

Is there a way I can specify letters a-z and replace it with an underscore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Simple,

```
str.replace(/[a-z]/g, '_')
```

to replace both upper and lowercase letters,

```
str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '_')
```

- `[a-z]` matches any lowercase letter.
- `g` global modifier helps to do the match globally.
- `i` case-insensitive modifier helps to do a case insensitive match.